# PJAX Header in Django

Tags: django, jquery, pushstate, pjax

I'm trying to pjaxify some of my views with jQuery-pjax and django-pjax. As I understand it, every pjax request sends an additional header **`X-PJAX: True`**. However, I can't find it anywhere even when (I think) my pjax codes work fine.

Base template **`stock-template.html`**:

```
<ul>
    <li><a data-pjax href="/basic/stock/" id="link-stock-index"></li>
    <li><a data-pjax href="/basic/stock/list/" id="link-stock-list"></li>
</ul>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($.support.pjax) {

      // I have tried the basic way
      // $(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '.tab-content)
      // here is a simplified version of using pjax through the click event

      // the container does get updated
      $(document).on('click', 'a[data-pjax]', function(event) {
        var container = $('.tab-content')
        $.pjax.click(event, {container: container})
      })

      // this gets executed
      $(document).on('pjax:complete', console.log('pjaxify complete'))

    }

});
</script>
```

In Template 1 (stock-index) **`stock.html`** and Template 2 (stock-list) **`stock-list.html`**  I extend the template and reuse the navigation above while putting a **`<div class="tab-content">`** in there as the designated container.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', stock.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^stock/$', stock.index),
    url(r'^stock/list', stock.slist),
)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    context_instance = RequestContext(request, {
        'pjax': request.META.get('HTTP_X_PJAX'), 
    })         
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'basic/stock/stock.html', context_instance)


def slist(request):
    items = Stock.objects.all()
    context_instance = RequestContext(request, {
        'pjax': request.META.get('HTTP_X_PJAX'),
    })
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'basic/stock/stock-list.html', context_instance)
```

To sum up, I think my code works because the PJAX scripts get executed and the `pjax:complete` was invoked. I just want to double check the header to make sure it's pjax rather than localhost being too fast to notice the page refresh. The problem is I can't see any X-PJAX header in Chrome or Firefox.

As you could see, I also tried to get the header and sent it to the template to display but it outputs `None`.

Please help.

Comment: Look at the network panel in firebug. If it is cleared when you navigate to a new page then pjax isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What do you mean by "it is cleared"?

Comment: If you are looking at the `net` panel, on the left there is a `clear` button which you can use to **manually** clear the log of net accesses. When you navigate to a new page the net log is **automatically** cleared. If pjax is successful then the net log will not be cleared.

Comment: thanks. It's not working then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was quite silly. PJAX wasn't able to swap my template with template-pjax because I forgot to load i18n in the pjax template. But I really appreciate @Sean Hogan's tips about checking the net panel.

Comment: Could you please share which pjax library did you used for django? Thanks

Comment: @Niks I used this https://github.com/eventials/django-pjax but it was more than 2 years ago. Nowadays I don't recommend doing plain PJAX anymore.

Comment: Ohh! then Could you please guide on this? Many Thanks

Comment: @Niks well the world has moved on since then. Now if you want to do single page application, use a framework for JavaScript such as Angular and communicate with your Django server in a RESTful manner.